# Mock response with repetitions in soapui

Tags: service, mocking, iteration, soapui

I'm trying to do mock response based on the request.
With a request like that:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <con:person>
     <person>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>18</age>
     </person>
  </con:person>
</soapenv:Body>
```

and a reponse like that

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <con:result>
     <person>
        <name>?</name>
        <age>?</age>
        <country>?</country>
        <city>?</city>
     </person>
  </con:result>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I can use elements from the request to take what i want in database and create the response.
But when i have a request with many person like that

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <con:person>
     <person>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>18</age>
     </person>
     <person>
        <name>Doe</name>
        <age>50</age>
     </person>
  </con:person>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I don't know how i can take all data from the request and how i can use them to create a response like that:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <con:result>
     <person>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>18</age>
        <country>France</country>
        <city>Paris</city>
     </person>
     <person>
        <name>Doe</name>
        <age>50</age>
        <country>Spain</country>
        <city>Madrid</city>
     </person>
  </con:result>
</soapenv:Body>
```

With the same number of person in the request and in the response.

I hope i was clear and i thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do something similar. First, I defined my mock response object as:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:stac="stackOverflow.question">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <stac:result>
        ${personElements}
      </stac:result>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I then created the content for `${personElements}` using this Groovy script:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

// An array from which county and city will be drawn randomly
def countryArray = [["Australia", "Perth"], 
    ["Spain", "Madrid"], 
    ["England","London"], 
    ["Brazil", "Rio"]]

def random = new Random()

// create XmlHolder for request content
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )

// Get the name and age values from the request
def requestItems = holder.getNodeValues( "//*:person/*:person/descendant::*") 

def writer = new StringWriter()
def personElements = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

// Build the response elements
for (int index = 0; index < requestItems.size() - 1; index += 2) {

    personElements.'stac:person'() {

        'stac:name'(requestItems[index])
        'stac:age'(requestItems[index+1])

        // Choose a random county and city from the array
        def randomIndex = random.nextInt(countryArray.size())
        'stac:country'(countryArray[randomIndex][0])
        'stac:city'(countryArray[randomIndex][1])
    }
}

// Add the newly created elements to the response
context.personElements = writer.toString()
```

This gave me a response like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:stac="stackOverflow.question">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <stac:result>
         <stac:person>
            <stac:name>Dolly Bonkers</stac:name>
            <stac:age>42</stac:age>
            <stac:country>Brazil</stac:country>
            <stac:city>Rio</stac:city>
         </stac:person>
         <stac:person>
            <stac:name>Mary Poppins</stac:name>
            <stac:age>82</stac:age>
            <stac:country>England</stac:country>
            <stac:city>London</stac:city>
         </stac:person>
         <stac:person>
            <stac:name>Bilbo Baggins</stac:name>
            <stac:age>102</stac:age>
            <stac:country>Australia</stac:country>
            <stac:city>Perth</stac:city>
         </stac:person>
         <stac:person>
            <stac:name>Johnny Hardcase</stac:name>
            <stac:age>22</stac:age>
            <stac:country>Spain</stac:country>
            <stac:city>Madrid</stac:city>
         </stac:person>
      </stac:result>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The script just takes random city and country values from a small array but you could come up with something better if you wanted consistent responses for certain names.